# Is removing this 2nd copy operation negligible

Tags: c++, compilation

Am I correct in thinking that 2 copies of `Bar` are performed when creating an instance of `Foo`?

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(Bar a) {
      a = a; // 2nd copy Bar performed
    }

    private:
    Bar a;
};

Foo f(myBar); // 1st copy of Bar performed
```

Would making the constructor parameter a constant reference reduce the number of copies down to one. Would modern compilers detect these 2 copies and optimise for me? So in effect, me trying to optimise is pointless as I already achieve that optimisation implicitly. Also would a constructor initialiser list result in anything different?

Ie;

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(const Bar& a) {
      a = a; // copy made
    }

    private:
    Bar a;
};

Foo f(myBar); // no copy made
```

Comment: In `a = a` you are assigning variable to itself this will be skipped if copy assignment operator is done correctly. Use different name for parameter either use `this->a = a`. If you compile it without any optimization value will be copied upon passing as an argument by value. But [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) will skip one copy in the first case.

Comment: The initialize list means the variable will be initialized once; instead of initialized and then copied, so it is a good idea

Answer (score 3):

For the 1st case:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(Bar b) {
      a = b;     // copy assignment operator called
    }

    private:
    Bar a;       // default ctor called
};

Foo f(myBar);    // copy ctor called
```

For the 2nd case:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(const Bar& b) {
      a = b;     // copy assignment operator called
    }

    private:
    Bar a;       // default ctor called
};

Foo f(myBar);    // nothing
```

And you can improve it further with [member initialize list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(const Bar& b) : a(b) {  // copy ctor called
    }

    private:
    Bar a;       // nothing
};

Foo f(myBar);    // nothing
```

PS: I fixed the parameter name as @teivaz commented.

Comment: Right, I missed the fact that copy assignment will be called instead of copy constructor.

Comment: @teivaz Yes, member initialize list is a good idea in general.

Comment: But still copy elision will optimize away copying object in the first case of `Foo f(myBar)`

Comment: @teivaz I doubted about it, since copy ctor and copy assignment operator is not the same thing.

Comment: yes, and copy elision eliminates copy and move constructors. That will be called when passing object by value